# Can op-amps be easily damaged?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm testing a circuit with a NE5532 op-amp in buffer configuration and I think I've somehow broken something.

These op-amps need 5V and -5V as power input. The 5V voltage is easy to obtain, but the -5V is hard to obtain without having a proper bench power source. I've ordered some ICL7660s to get -5V from the 5V power rail in my circuit, but they are not arriving on time, so I've hooked up some AA batteries and I'm able to obtain -5.2V in theop-amp Vcc- pin. The positive voltage Vcc+ ended up between 4.8V and 5V. There's a difference of about 0.2V. Can this be problematic?

My first attempt succeeded, but the proto board was so messy I decided to start a new circuit in another protoboard. And now this very same chip no longer works. The output, which should be a square wave about 40mV peak to peak, centered at 0V, is suddenly 4.5V DC.

Do these things get easily damaged? I might have applied 5V and nothing in Vcc- for about a second, or even floating Vcc+ and -5V in Vcc-.

Comment: Sounds like if it worked before you reassembled it, but doesn't after, you should probably double check your wiring. The NE5532 is rated for up to +/-15V, so you are *unlikely* to have damaged it.

Comment: I've spent more than 20 minutes checking the wires and measuring voltages, and it looks ok. I thought I might have fried the internals when connecting the Vccs one after the other instead of both at the same time.

Comment: Could you post a schematic and photo of your circuit.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide a picture. It was such a mess... As for the circuit, it is just an op-amp in buffer configuration: The negative input wired to the output, and the positive input as the actual and only input. Vout should be equal to Vin as the gain is 1.

Comment: My rule of thumb is always buy 3 components  (when they are cheap and esd sensitive). Any chance you have another one around or similar?

Comment: @Beng I'll try other chips tomorrow.